# Different href for links to open inline v/s new tab

Tags: href

I have a single page application (MySPA). The MySPA is loaded as a stand alone application or as part of another iframe based SPA where MySPA is loaded in an iframe.

When loaded as stand alone, the url looks like http://..../mySPA#home

When loaded as part of another SPA, the url looks like http://..../foo/mySPA#home

The challenge I am facing is ...
The links inside MySPA have their href="#dashboard" or href="#listView". When I click on these links, they do the right thing in both the environments.
But when user right-clicks and "Open in New Tab" or Command+Click, a new tab is opened and the iframe context is lost and MySPA goes in a stand alone mode.

I was wondering if there are any patterns around this and what is the cleanest way to solve this problem.

The BASE HREF solution does not work because the links have to be dynamic in this case (different href for opening inline and a different href for open in new tab).

Comment: Does your SPA know it's within a different SPA?

Comment: Yes, MySPA knows that it resides in another SPA